# How do I call a gRPC Server from a NodeJS client when using generated *_pb.js files?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I do not want to distribute the proto files to customers, so I code-gened _pb.js files from the respective protos with help from [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/node/static_codegen)

But I cannot figure out how to "call" the function running on the grpc server.

Here's the relevant bit :

```
// commp_grpc_pb.js

// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!

'use strict';
var grpc = require('grpc');
var commp_pb = require('./commp_pb.js');

function serialize_optfoo_FooReply(arg) {
  if (!(arg instanceof commp_pb.FooReply)) {
    throw new Error('Expected argument of type optfoo.FooReply');
  }
  return Buffer.from(arg.serializeBinary());
}

function deserialize_optfoo_FooReply(buffer_arg) {
  return commp_pb.FooReply.deserializeBinary(new Uint8Array(buffer_arg));
}

function serialize_optfoo_FooRequest(arg) {
  if (!(arg instanceof commp_pb.FooRequest)) {
    throw new Error('Expected argument of type optfoo.FooRequest');
  }
  return Buffer.from(arg.serializeBinary());
}

function deserialize_optfoo_FooRequest(buffer_arg) {
  return commp_pb.FooRequest.deserializeBinary(new Uint8Array(buffer_arg));
}


var FooService = exports.FooService = {
  fooFunc: {
    path: '/optfoo.Foo/FooFunc',
    requestStream: false,
    responseStream: false,
    requestType: commp_pb.FooRequest,
    responseType: commp_pb.FooReply,
    requestSerialize: serialize_optfoo_FooRequest,
    requestDeserialize: deserialize_optfoo_FooRequest,
    responseSerialize: serialize_optfoo_FooReply,
    responseDeserialize: deserialize_optfoo_FooReply,
  },
};

exports.FooClient = grpc.makeGenericClientConstructor(FooService);
```

I have made my client

```
const grpc__ = require('../services/commp_grpc_pb');
let client = new grpc__.FooClient('localhost:50051',
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
```

I have already generated my `FooRequest`. How do I pass that request to gRPC server?

Comment: HI, client.js file sends a request to server.js. Proto file defines the type. 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/node/static_codegen/greeter_client.js#L35

can you be specific what is not working?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I do not have the equivalent of a `sayHello()` function. For me it would be called something like `FooFunc()`. I see `FooFunc` inside `FooService` (which is defined in the _grpc_pb.js file) but do not know how to use that.

Comment: Ahh nvm. I was calling FooFunc(); it should have been fooFunc(). Closing question.